# query in mysql to jooq

Tags: mysql, jooq

hello Im struggling to rewrite this is jooq, could anyone help me?

```
SELECT t.id,
         t.count,
         @running_total := @running_total + t.count AS cumulative_sum
    FROM TABLE t
    JOIN (SELECT @running_total := 0) r
ORDER BY t.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jOOQ currently doesn't support this MySQL-specific syntax out of the box, but you can easily work around any missing jOOQ feature by resorting to the [plain SQL templating API](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/):

```java
// Assuming you're using the code generator
MyTable t = MY_TABLE.as("t");

DSL.using(configuration)
   .select(
       t.ID, 
       t.COUNT,
       field("@running_total := @running_total + {0}", t.COUNT).as("cumulative_sum"))
   .from(t)
   .crossJoin(select(field("@running_total := 0")))
   .orderBy(t.ID)
   .fetch();
```